# Page paint time stays high after css filter is removed

Tags: css, css-filters

I use a div as a frame to add a css filter on whatever its content.

```
<div id="blurbox_wholescreen" class="blurbox">
    ...page content...
</div>
```

The filter is activated via css class.

```
.blurbox
{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.blurbox.blured
{
    filter: blur(4px) brightness(80%) contrast(130%);
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px) brightness(80%) contrast(130%);
}
```

When I toggle the class, the content of the blurbox gets blured.

```
function menu_toggle()
{
    ...
    $("#blurbox_wholescreen").toggleClass("blured");
    ...
}
```

The 'Page paint time' displayed by the Chrome Inspector is low first (around 7ms) and as expected jumps up (to about 25ms) when the filter is applied. So far so good.

What bothers me is that it stays that high when I untoggle the ".blured" class again. I anticipate that the FPS should go back to default, as the performance heavy filter is removed. But it doesn't and I am puzzled.

Explanation somebody or tips how to tackle that?